# AppEngine applications running on pypy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pypy

Is it possible to deploy python services on Google's AppEngine using [pypy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy) as runtime environment?

Being a JIT compiled implementation, and seeing its good use cases on web apps, it makes sense it could be integrated with App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that [custom python environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) can be created in Google AppEngine. These require only a Dockerfile defining the project.

Comment: Hi, did you succeed to run PyPy on GAE? I would like to know about your experience.